# Circumvent death by hypothermia

Tags: death, oxygenation, hypothermia

What I've read seems to indicate that hypothermia leads to death by stopping the heart, which means your cells slowly die from oxygen deprivation.

1. Is that accurate?
2. Suppose you mechanically pumped a person's blood as they got colder, and also oxygenated their blood. Would this enable them to survive?  For instance, could you use this as a kind of partial cryosleep?

Comment: Ahem. Every death is eventually a stop of the heart and oxygen deprivation. Blood loss leads to that, brain death tends to, heart strokes do. Interesting is **why** the heart stops.

Comment: @Narusan Well, fair, aside from some poisonings or major brain trauma, etc.  I feel like most other initial causes of death are not as easily reversible as "they are cold", though; my understanding is that they'll try to keep blood in you and your heart pumping while they try to fix a knife wound.  So after a fashion, part of the question is, "are there any irreversible changes that being cold causes, that do not stem from the heart stopping"?